# Joining two datasets using fuzzy logic

Tags: r, join, string-matching, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison

I’m trying to do a fuzzy logic join in R between two datasets:

- first data set has the name of a location and a column called `config`
- second data set has the name of a location and two additional attributes that need to be summarized before they are joined to the first data set.

I would like to use the `name` column to join between the two data sets. However the `name` column may have additional or leading characters in either data set or have one word contained inside of a larger word. So for example if we looked at these two data sets, I'd like the name OPAL to join to the OPALAS, and SAUSALITO Y to join to SAUSALITO.

```
Dataset1:    
     Name           Config
     ALTO D         BB
     CONTRA         ST
     EIGHT A        DD
     OPALAS         BB
     SAUSALITO Y    AA
     SOLANO J       ST

Dataset2:    
    Name       Age     Rank
    ALTO D     50      2
    ALTO D     20      6
    CONTRA     10      10
    CONTRA     15      15
    EIGHTH     18      21
    OPAL       19      4
    SAUSALITO  2       12
    SOLANO     34      43
```

Code for Summarizing of Dataset2

```
Data2a <- summaryBy(Age ~ Name,FUN=c(mean), data=Data2,na.rm=TRUE)
Data2b <- summaryBy(Rank ~ Name,FUN=c(sum), data=Data2,na.rm=TRUE)
Data2 <- data.frame(Data2a$Name, Data2a$Age.mean, Data2b$Rank.sum)

Desired Outcome:
    Name        Config  Age   Rank
    ALTO D      BB      35    8
    CONTRA      ST      12.5  25
    EIGHT A     DD      18    21
    OPALAS      BB      19    4
    SAUSALITO Y AA      12    5
    SOLANO J    ST      34    43
```

Comment: check out the [`fuzzyjoin`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to join the two datasets, using the fuzzyjoin package:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_inner_join(Dataset1, Data2,
     by ="Name", distance_col = NULL)
```