# Fuzzy Logic Join using two columns

Tags: r, fuzzyjoin

I'm using the r package fuzzyjoin to join two data sets. Currently I am joining on one [column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359860/joining-two-datasets-using-fuzzy-logic-in-r), and would like to join on two.

- first dataset has the name of a location and a column called config
- second dataset has the name of a location and two three
  attributes
- I would like to join on two columns name and TM

I've tried adding in the column names I wish to join as a vector but this doesn't seem to work. I get an error that says:

- Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list. Problem
  variables: col.

  ```
  #This works to join on 1 column
  library(fuzzyjoin)
  stringdist_inner_join(Dataset1, Data2, by ="Name", distance_col = NULL)

  #Joiningontwocolumns
  stringdist_inner_join(Dataset1, Dataset2, by =c("Name","TM"), distance_col = NULL)
  ```

Dataset1:

```
 Name           Config     TM
 ALTO D         BB         T
 CONTRA         ST         D
 EIGHT A        DD         D
 OPALAS         BB         T
 SAUSALITO Y    AA         D
 SOLANO J       ST         D
```

Dataset2:

```
 Name       Age     Rank    TM
 ALTO D     50      2       T
 ALTO D     20      6       D
 CONTRA     10      10      D
 CONTRA     15      15      T
 EIGHTH     18      21      T
 OPAL       19      4       T
 SAUSALITO  2       12      D
 SOLANO     34      43      D
```

Comment: try `by =c("Name"="TM")`. source: the examples in `?fuzzyjoin::stringdist_inner_join`

Comment: Seeing the example in github, you would need to write the following: `by = c(Name = "TM")`

Comment: @jazzurro, Thanks, it worked to a certain extent. I would say the fuzzyjoin package has issues for multiple joins.

Comment: @steppermotor I see. I am playing with the package now. I guess I will see some issues then. Thanks for telling me this!

Answer (score 2):

It took a while for me to figure out but I believe the correct syntax for multiple column joins is:

```
stringdist_inner_join(data1, data2, 
                      by = list(x = c("Name", "TM"), y = c("Name", "TM")), 
                      distance_col = NULL))
```

Comment: (this is for when columns may not be named the same...)